# Azure pipelines: What is the name of the pipeline resource?

Tags: azure-devops, continuous-integration, azure-pipelines, continuous-deployment, azure-repos

Im new in Azure DevOps and want to trigger a pipeline by another pipeline.

i follow [this documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/pipeline-triggers?view=azure-devops)

the following section is described there:

```
# this is being defined in app-ci pipeline
resources:
  pipelines:
  - pipeline: securitylib   # Name of the pipeline resource
    source: security-lib-ci # Name of the pipeline referenced by the pipeline resource
    project: FabrikamProject # Required only if the source pipeline is in another project
    trigger: true # Run app-ci pipeline when any run of security-lib-ci completes
```

I have no idea what the pipeline resource is. (property `pipeline`) I tried the name of the repo but the repo name contains a dot, what does not match the required pattern.

[image]

Can anyone tell me where i find the value for this property?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> - pipeline: securitylib specifies the name of the pipeline resource, and is used when referring to the pipeline resource from other parts of the pipeline, such as pipeline resource variables.

is a name for the pipeline resource. This is not pipeline name in Azure Devops. It it is like

```
- job: JobA
```

So this is just a name and you can put here anything what pass character limitation.