# Need to call multiple pipelines from another pipeline : How to trigger resources for ADO pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, devops

I need to trigger multiple pipelines from another pipeline. For this i got ADO resources in YAML to configure. A resource is anything used by a pipeline that lives outside the pipeline.

**Source** : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/resources?view=azure-devops&tabs=example#resources-builds

Steps i followed:

1. Created a GIT repo and created a pipeline yaml on it. This is supposed to be a dummy repo that would only trigger other pipelines.

The yaml there is :

```
# Starter pipeline
# Start with a minimal pipeline that you can customize to build and deploy your code.
# Add steps that build, run tests, deploy, and more:
# https://aka.ms/yaml

trigger:
- none


resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: 02-understanding-stages-pipeline
      project: azure-devops-kubernetes-terraform
      branch: master
      source: 02-understanding-stages-pipeline
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
        stages:
          - Build
          - DevDeploy
```

Error in YAML

```
An error occurred while loading the YAML build pipeline. The array must contain at l 
least one element. Parameter name: stages
```

02-understanding-stages-pipeline is another pipeline in another project. I need to trigger and set of other such pipelines from this pipeline.

Question :

1. Suggestions as how to trigger pipelines from other pipelines
2. Any idea how to resolve the error i get
3. What are **source** and **pipeline** under pipelines? Can explain briefly?

Thanks in advance!!

Answer (score 1):

> Suggestions as how to trigger pipelines from other pipelines

You can use [Trigger Build Task extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=benjhuser.tfs-extensions-build-tasks) as following:

```yaml
- task: TriggerBuild@3
displayName: 'Trigger a new build of Validate-BuildVariable Update'
inputs:
    buildDefinition: 'Your build name'
    useSameBranch: false
    branchToUse: master
    waitForQueuedBuildsToFinish: true
    authenticationMethod: 'OAuth Token'
    password: $(System.AccessToken)
```

Or [Rest API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/pipelines/runs/run%20pipeline?view=azure-devops-rest-6.0)

`POST https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/pipelines/{pipelineId}/runs?api-version=6.0-preview.1`

> Any idea how to resolve the error i get

I made a test and this works for me:

```yaml
trigger: none


resources:
  pipelines:
    - pipeline: pipelineUnderstanding
      branch: master
      source: kmadof.dm-so-47-multi-stage
      trigger:
        branches:
          - master
        stages:
          - Build
          - Deploy
steps:
- script: echo 'siema'
```

I would suggest you to check your stages if your pipelie has exactly as you wrote here.

> What are source and pipeline under pipelines? Can explain briefly?

Source is

> name of the pipeline that produces an artifact

Pipeline is

> identifier for the resource used in pipeline resource variables

It is just an alias of resource object. Please check it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68210395/azure-pipelines-what-is-the-name-of-the-pipeline-resource/68213462#68213462)

Comment: The yaml file contains resources tag. When the pipeline gets triggered, it dosnt triggers "resources" and hence no external build is done. The build only runs the "steps" part and echoes the message. Any idea how to trigger resources tag?

Comment: Using the plugin, hangs the ADO for a longer time.

Comment: Wrong order. Let's say you have two pipelines 1 and 2. And you want to have pipelines 2 triggerd by pipeline 1. Then resources you should put in pipeline 2 with settings regarding pipeline 1.  In this way pipeline 2 will be triggered by execution of pipeline 1, however this is non blocking. Extension is blocking. Here you trigger pipeline 2 by putting task in pipeline 1.